# Mapview blank in Android

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, android-mapview

I'm having a problem with my project in react-native. In iOS, this is working but in Android it is completely blank and doesn't show anything.

Here is my class code:

```
class Three extends React.Component{
    getInitialState() {
        return {
          initialPosition: 0,
          lastPosition: 0,
          annotations: [{
            latitude: 23,
            longitude: 121,
          }],
        };
      }

    render() {
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <MapView 
              style={styles.map}
              region={{
          latitude: 25.6589,
          longitude: 36.5487,
          latitudeDelta: 0.00922,
          longitudeDelta: 0.00421,}}
          showsUserLocation={true}

            />

          </View>
        );
      }

      regionChange(region){
        this.setState({
          annotations:[{
            latitude:region.latitude,
            longitude:region.longitude,
          }]
        });
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

MapView is not supported in Android. You should use [react native maps](https://github.com/lelandrichardson/react-native-maps)
for cross platform.

You can check [this](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/mapview.html) link for more info